# Model of access rights in database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

In web application (laravel 5.3 based, mysql) there are three main models: `User`, `Department` and `UserRole` and many other models (`tickets`, `tasks`, etc.) `User` has manager (another `User` on top level).

`User` belongs to `Department`. Departments make up hierarchy. User has some role which allows him, for example, to see tasks in his department and in all departments below his department.

For example, user in department of zero level can see all tasks in system.

User in department of level one can see tasks in his department, in department of level two which is direct child of department of his department and so on. There can be many levels (up to 10).

Let's say I want to show all visible tasks for user in department B (see picture). I must query database to get tasks in department B, then in department D, then order them by modification time and paginate to display first page.

[image]

Main problem here: in department B there are 100 000 tasks, in department D there are 200 000 tasks. Such system can not be scaled well.

I am afraid of the following problem:

To display all tasks visible for user in department B I would use something like this: select * from tasks where creator_id in (`long list of user ids which can be queried for currently authenticated user, if this user in department b, than here will be list of user ids in departments B and C, task has no connection to department, only to user`). How can I avoid such queries?

What are my options?

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: When a task is completed, add a `completed_at` flag, and utilize a query scope to ignore the querying of those records. a few hundred thousand rows should not be problematic, tens of millions should. Can we see the code that you're using, and answer @AkhterAlaminFarhan's question too?

Comment: What if I want to display all tasks no matter what their status is?

Comment: @changer Then you would use `::chunk` and `paginate` so you don't end up displaying that many rows; no one in their right mind would display hundreds of thousands of rows to a user.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, read latest paragraph with question. I warry about big queries.

Answer (score 0):

Give each department number and then write query something like:

Example for user from department 1:

```
select * from tasks
join department on department.id = task.department_id where department.number <= 1;
```

EDIT:

```
select * from tasks
join users on users.id = tasks.user_id 
join department on department.id = users.department_id where department.number <= 1;
```

Comment: Tasks are assigned to users. In this app I can not assign task to department because user can be moved into another department.